# Difference Between Static or NoneStatic Methods in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, static

I need a method that return me some parameters in controllers this is implementation of it:

```
    public List<Parameter> GetParameters(FormCollection collection) {

        List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        List<string> parameterNames = new List<string>();

        //Get Parameters Names and Values

        return parameters;
    }
```

I use this method in all of controllers, So I think about 3 option that I have to define it:

1-For any controller class define it in that controller like this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller {

   public List<Parameter> GetParameters(FormCollection collection) {

   //

    }
  }
```

2-Define it in static class as static method:

```
public static class GeneralMethods {

   public static List<Parameter> GetParameters(FormCollection collection) {

   //

    }
  }
```

3-Define it as a None Static :

```
public class GeneralMethods {

   public List<Parameter> GetParameters(FormCollection collection) {

   //

    }
  }
```

which one is better? which one have better performance? or any other option for define methods that used in many controllers?
what is your suggestion?

Comment: Performance-wise you are not likely to notice any difference between the three approaches. What do you mean by "better"? For what? Usability? Readability? Maintenance? Something else?

Comment: @Oded I don't know in web, which one is usual or any difference in performance or page load time or server performance

Comment: As I said, when in comes to performance you are not going to get any appreciable differences.

Comment: I would go with option 3, not for performance but because you could then extract an interface from that class and mock it when unit testing your controller actions.  That said the method itself feels a bit off, it's not clear why you need it in the first place and accessing FormCollection is usually bad practice.

Comment: @Betty why accessing FormCollection is bad?

Comment: If this is something you're doing across all controllers, then I'd suggest option 4, which would be to make a custom model binder for it.

Comment: @ngm what relation between a custom model an define a method? what do you mean of custom model binder?

Comment: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Comment: It's only relevant in your particular example, because the method that you're asking about is pulling information out of the request.  This is what model binding is for.  Basically in this case it's kind of a specialised version of your option 3.

Comment: In fact, thinking about it, if your form is set up correctly, you can probably just have a List<Parameter> parameter on your action methods, and rely on the default model binder.  But anyway this is maybe better left for another question, as it's a bit of a tangent from your original question.

Comment: Accessing FormCollection is bad because you miss out on a lot of the nice features of model binding and validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be no performance impact in any of the three. (Though last approach will create separate object each time,it will be gracefully handled by GC).

**approach 1:** NO, as a standard practice we should not duplicate the code.

**approach 2:** YES, if your method depends only on the input parameter.

**approach 3:** YES, if you need to set up some instance variable and your method depends on them.

**suggested approach:** (approach 1+ approach 3)
If this method is common to all of your controller (or most), declare a base controller with this method and inherit all other controller from it.

Static methods will not be a problem as any variable declared with in a method are with in scope of the method.